# Unexpected character when printing char array

Tags: c

I am trying to build a cron expression parser

I have the following methods (Work in progress):

```
Cron parseCron(char* cronStr) {
  char *dup = strdup(cronStr);
  char* p;
  char* cronAtoms[5];
  int i = 0;
  p = strtok(dup, " ");
  while(p != NULL){
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    cronAtoms[i] = p;
    i++;

  }
  return generateCron(cronAtoms);

}
```

and this one:

```
Cron generateCron(char **cronAtoms){
  Cron cron;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", cronAtoms[i]);
  }
  return cron;
}
```

The input string is `"* * * * *"`
 when I print the results here's what I get:

```
*
*
*
*
@
```

I have to admit I am a bit surprised, but I think I understand why. The last pointer stored in the `cronAtoms` array might include the NULL terminating character or maybe some cruft in the adjacent memory. I am no C expert, so it's entirely possible I am wrong about my assumption.

More importantly, I'd like to know a fool-proof way correctly extract the last character (have "*" instead of "@")

Comment: you skip the first * because you call strtok twice before you set index 0 of cronAtoms. You only set the 4 indexes of cronAtoms. The @ is completely random. It could have been anything.

Comment: ... so move `p = strtok(NULL, " ");` down two lines so it follows `i++;`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, which would have been evident to you if you had applied your code to input containing fields that were distinguishable from each other.

This ...

```
p = strtok(dup, " ");
```

... results in `p` pointing to the first token in the string.  When you then proceed as you do ...

```
while(p != NULL){
  p = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

... you point `p` at the *next* token, if any, losing the first.

This bit is more or less ok ...

```
  cronAtoms[i] = p;
  i++;
```

... but it does not protect against overrunning the bounds of the array in the event that the input has more than five fields (never assume that your input will be valid).

**Moreover**, you do not initialize elements of `cronAtoms`, so if you run out of fields before assigning all of them (as you do in this case, on account of ignoring the first, or as you might with invalid input) then the unwritten elements contain garbage when `generateCron()` examines them.

As an aside, `strdup()` allocates memory which you are obligated to free.  If you do not do so -- which you do not -- then your program leaks that memory.